# How to Add PHP Variables in a Jquery Notification

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing variables from php to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141860/passing-variables-from-php-to-javascript)

I am using [this awesome](http://dev.thrivingkings.com/read/Sticky-A-super-simple-notification-system-built-with-jQuery) jQuery Stick Notification Plugin which creates notifications upon clicking various buttons. 
I used the following code to display the notification box...

```
$(".notify").click(function() {
     $.sticky('The page has loaded!');
});
```

Can i make it display some PHP variables in place of static text message?

Hope i've made it clear enough.

Comment: you mean to say let it communicate with your php? in other words ajax?

Comment: no, i was so dumb to not figuring out the simplest method :( nevermind.. its solved :)

Comment: kindly share how did you solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=passing+php+variables+to+javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without making asynchronous HTTP calls, you will have to insert the PHP variable at server-side:

```
$(".notify").click(function() {
    $.sticky('<?php echo htmlentities($message); ?>');
});
```

Wrap it with `htmlentities()` just in case `$message` contains some chars that make the JavaScript string invalid.

Comment: some chars such as a single quote ' ???

Comment: Yup, or linebreaks, or some other chars.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can like

```
$(".notify").click(function() {    
 $.sticky('<?php echo "The page has been loaded"; ?>');    
});
```