# How can i add a php variable into javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/7d5339867b063fd0/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/".$area.".json";
?>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
 url : ,
dataType : "jsonp",
success : function(parsed_json) {
var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
alert("This is an example of a web service outputting using Json. The current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
}
});
});

</script>
```

How can i add the "$url" variable into the javascript code at the location " url : "here",

Thanks

Comment: You could echo it out?

Comment: Have you tried ````url : "<?php echo $url; ?>"```` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing variables from php to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141860/passing-variables-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put it like that:

```
url : "<?=$url?>",
```

OR (best way):

```
url : "<?php echo $url; ?>",
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php
    $url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/7d5339867b063fd0/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/".$area.".json";
    ?>

    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
     url : "<?=$url?>",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
    var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
    var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
    alert("This is an example of a web service outputting using Json. The current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
    }
    });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Data from $url need to be between double quotes to be valid: `"<?=$url?>"`

Comment: I have put in double quotes just see pls @Magicprog.fr

Answer (score 1):

```
url : "<?php print $url ?>",
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
var jsVar = <?=json_encode($phpVar)?>;
```

or in your case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: <?=json_encode($url)?>,
    dataType: "jsonp"
    // ...
});
```

This is the safest way, and works with any data (arrays etc.).